# User defined API generation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

When I am analyzing an undocumented code base I like to document the "most important" methods as a single group.  I think of it as an API consisting of methods I consider useful.  I can go into object browser and find useful objects.  However, when I copy a method I only get the fully qualified type name.  I want this along with public methods (and optionally their XML doc's).

I want this process to be efficient.  Documentation that can be updated with relatively little effort. Ideally, I would like to end up with something similar to the formatted layout displayed in a browser when viewing a WSDL.  Is there a way to generate concise, updateable documentation for objects that I pick?

Comment: Perhaps you want doxygen and the [`INTERNAL_DOCS`](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/config.html#cfg_internal_docs) configuration setting?

Comment: @BenVoigt - That tool does even more than I was hoping for.  I have not found a way to generate a simple case "pick one class and look at the documentation".  However, the generated web page is so good this should work even better.

Comment: With `\internal` magic comments along with `INTERNAL_DOCS = NO` you can hide less important members from the documentation.  And then regenerate it with `INTERNAL_DOCS = YES` to see all of them.

Comment: @BenVoigt This is great.  If you want to put down an answer of sorts for this I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my favorite ways to document source code (including but not limited to hand-written comments added to the code) is the doxygen tool.  It supports C# well.

Since you mentioned wanting to see only the most "useful" members, you can flag the less important ones with the `\internal` doxygen command (in the special comments).  Then you can display docs for only the most useful using the `INTERNAL_DOCS = NO` configuration when generating the HTML (set `INTERNAL_DOCS = YES` to get the comprehensive version including every member).

Doxygen also provides powerful grouping tools for writing high-level documentation for a group of classes or group of members of a class.  You'll definitely want to look through the examples in the manual.